# Using Mask to trace transparent space inside Text

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, mask

I have a text which has transparent space in it. I wanted to trace that space in order to use it as a clipping mask for an image.

[image]

I selected the space using magic wand. I some how did something and converted the selection into a visible filled space in a new layer.

[image]

I'm not able to do it again because 'Apply Layer Mask' is disabled right now; I don't know why.

Could someone help me out how to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

*This answer is an alternative to Vicki's method*

You can select the inner spaces, then convert the selection to a mask.

1. Add the image you want to mask and the text layer to PS.

[image: PS img and txt]

2. Select the inner transparancy in the text with magic wand. (You can also ctrl-click the layer thumbnail in the layers panel, then invert the selection and remove the outer transparency from the selection)

[image: select inner transparency]

3. Now select your image and click 'Add layer mask'.

[image: add layer mask]

4. **optional**: hide the text layer

[image: hide layer]

Answer (score 1):

Let's start over, since it looks like your happy accident produced a semi-transparent "Let's Ride" mask and it makes it hard to see what's going on...

To keep things simple, I'm starting with just a Background Layer (with the visibility turned off for now) and a Text Layer.

[image: Start Here]

1. With your Text Layer selected, use the **Magic Wand** to select the space inside each of the letters. **Hold Shift** as you click inside each letter to continue adding to your selection. (Note: The Magic Wand's tolerance level defaults to 32, that should be fine for the type of selection you're doing.)

[image: Step 1]

2. After all your letter shapes have been added to the selection, **create a New Layer**

[image: Step 2]

3. Go to **Edit > Fill** to fill the selection on your New Layer with a solid color. Any color is fine, just make sure the **opacity is set to 100%**.

[image: Step 3]

4. Now that your text shapes are filled in, **deselect** your selection (ctrl+D, or command+D if you're on a Mac), and **click the eyeball icon** next to the Text Layer to turn off it's visibility. You should only see your solid-colored Mask Shape now.

[image: Step 4]

6. Let's mask something! **Create a New Layer** just above your Mask Shape, and paste in your image.

[image: Step 5]

7. **Right click your Image Layer**, and select **"Create Clipping Mask"**.

[image]

At this point you can toggle on your original Text Layer if you still want it, and/or your Background Layer to see things better.

Comment: There's no need for steps 2-5. You can create a layer mask directly from a selection. Just select the area you want and click layer mask (alt-click for inverse layer mask)

Comment: @PieBie True! Glad you added it as an answer, got an upvote from me. :)

Comment: Thanks Vicki! Got the 'revival' badge because of that :D